# How can I perform error handling in Stencil app

Tags: error-handling, web-component, stenciljs

I have a simple case:

```
<component-a>
 <component-b/>
</component-a>
```

Im I able to catch error from component B in component A?
What the best practice to handle error in stencil app?
Is there a kind of react error boundary?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and define a custom `@Event` (e.g. errorEvent) in component-b that fires every time that the error occurs, and the component-a can `@Listen("errorEvent")` and do what needs to be done.

Comment: I think it doesn't work because this way I will be forced to manually wrap code with try/cath but Im looking for something react error boundary which allows to automatically catch error during rendering, look like stenciljs doesn't have any solution https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1398, https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/370